# Doubt about identity on the Wikipedia page Feynman slash notation

Tags: notation, dirac-matrices

I have the following doubt about the identity in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_slash_notation) page:
$$ {a\!\!\!/}{a\!\!\!/}  \equiv   a^\mu a_\mu \cdot I_4 = a^2 \cdot I_4 $$
however:
$${a\!\!\!/}{a\!\!\!/}=a^{\mu}\gamma_{\mu}a_{\mu}\gamma^{\mu} = a^2 \gamma_{\mu}\gamma^{\mu}=4 a^2 I_{4}$$

Comment: You have repeated the index $\mu$ four times and should only do so twice. The a components are not contracted until later, as in the answer below

Comment: @lux That seems more like an answer that an comment.

Answer (score 2):

Since $a$ is a vector, its entries $a_\mu$ are just numbers and they commute with everything

$$ {a\!\!\!/}{a\!\!\!/} = a_\mu\gamma^\mu a_\nu\gamma^\nu = \gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu a_\mu a_\nu,$$

using $\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu + \gamma^\nu\gamma^\mu = 2 \eta^{\mu\nu}I_4 $ to get $\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu = 2 \eta^{\mu\nu}I_4 - \gamma^\nu\gamma^\mu  $, the expression above becomes:

$$ \gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu a_\mu a_\nu = (2 \eta^{\mu\nu}I_4 - \gamma^\nu\gamma^\mu) a_\mu a_\nu = 2 I_4 a^\mu a_\mu  - \gamma^\nu\gamma^\mu a_\mu a_\nu.$$

The last term, via commutation of $a_\mu$, can be written $\gamma^\nu\gamma^\mu a_\mu a_\nu =  a_\nu\gamma^\nu a_\mu\gamma^\mu = {a\!\!\!/}{a\!\!\!/}$. Bring it to the LHS to get:

$$2 {a\!\!\!/}{a\!\!\!/} = 2 I_4 a^\mu a_\mu, $$

$$ \Rightarrow {a\!\!\!/}{a\!\!\!/} = I_4\,a^\mu a_\mu = I_4\, a^2.$$

Answer (score 1):

OP has an error in the application of the Einstein summation convention. In their expression
$a^{\mu}\gamma_{\mu}a_{\mu}\gamma^{\mu}$ the index $\mu$ is repeated 4 times. OP then incorrectly sees the terms $a^{\mu}a_{\mu}$ and $\gamma_{\mu}\gamma^{\mu}$ and applies the summation convention individually to them.

However in the expression $a\!\!\!/a\!\!\!/$ the contractions are between the vector $a$ and a gamma matrix and *not* between $a$ and itself:
$$a\!\!\!/a\!\!\!/= a_{\mu}\gamma^{\mu}\,\, a_{\nu}\gamma^{\nu}$$
which makes it clear that there is not yet an inner product of $a$ with itself. From here we take advantage of symmetry of the product $a_{\mu}a_{\nu}$ to take only the symmetric part of the decomposition $\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu} = \frac{1}{2}\{\gamma^{\mu}, \gamma^{\nu}\} + \frac{1}{2}[\gamma^{\mu}, \gamma^{\nu}]$. We get
$$a_{\mu}\gamma^{\mu}\, a_{\nu}\gamma^{\nu} = a_{\mu}a_{\nu}\frac{1}{2}\{\gamma^{\mu}, \gamma^{\nu}\} = a_{\mu}a_{\nu}\eta^{\mu\nu}I_{4} = a^{2}I_{4}. $$